# Samba install broke openvpn

Tags: linux, samba, raspberry-pi

I used http://jankarres.de/2013/05/raspberry-pi-openvpn-vpn-server-installieren/ for installing openvpn. I followed the instructions to the letter and everything worked fine.

My client connected to the openvpn server and all of its traffic was routed through the openvpn server.

I used this for a few week.

Yesterday I installed samba:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Added a folder to /etc/samba/smb.conf.

Samba worked fine inside my local network. Today I connected with my openvpn client to the server and I can only reach my local network.

What workes:

- Connect to the openvpn server
- Access Server inside the local lan
- Openvpn server can ping google.com just fine. Everything works

What's now broken:

- Openvpn client can no longer lookup dns names
- Openvpn client can no longer access any source outside the openvpn lan

Openvpn client route:

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         11.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
11.8.0.0        11.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
11.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
#ExternalIP#    10.0.2.2        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

Openvpn server route:

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.16.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.16.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
11.8.0.0        11.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
11.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Gateway (Router Local lan) 10.10.16.1
Local lan 10.10.16.0
Openvpn network 11.8.0.0

Again: I have changed none of the openvpn settings...

Answer (score 0):

You are using for your OpenVPN network some public, routable addresses (11.8.0.0/24) instead of private addresses. Change these addresses to something private, like 192.168.115.0/24 or 10.171.43.0/24, and check again.

By the way, 11.8.0.5, according to whatismyipaddress.com, corresponds to DoD Network Information Center in Columbus, Ohio: I bet they are quite unwilling to resolve your DNS queries and to route your stuff.